# Combine class and Biblatex citations

Tags: biblatex, citing, combine

I have 3 articles that use biblatex citations and all of them have a reference-list in the end. Now I'd like to combine all three articles in a main document using the combine-class. However, how can that be done with the biblatex citations so so that each part of the main document has its own reference list based on seperate .bib-files. The main document should also come with an overall introduction (like published conference proceedings).

So what do I have to write into the preamble of the main document (combine class)? I need to load the biblatex package but was else needs to be specified? And do I need to modify my single articles?

Comment: Maybe `refsection` and `refsegment` can help you [(§§ 3.6.4 seq. in the `biblatex` documentation)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) as well as [(§ 3.11.2)](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf).

Comment: did you find out anything on this?

Comment: Are there any news here?